# WSO2 APIM/IS: How to configure default identity provider

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I have created a custom federated authenticator and configure it in an identity provider called 'kbank'.

How can I configure to have all Service Providers use this Identity Providers by default without having to individually specify it for each Service Providers. Since in API Manager, each application is created as Service Provider so there will be a lot and increasing Service Providers in our system.

In Service Provider configuration page I can see there is an option for "Default" but I don't how to specify the default.

[image]

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35343448/set-wso2-identity-provider-as-default-idp-for-new-applications), the solution for my problem is I have to modify `<APIM_Home>\repository\conf\identity\service-providers\default.xml` as follow

```
<ServiceProvider>
    <ApplicationID>1</ApplicationID>
    <ApplicationName>default</ApplicationName>
    <Description>Default Service Provider</Description>
    <InboundAuthenticationConfig>
        <InboundAuthenticationRequestConfigs>
            <InboundAuthenticationRequestConfig>
                <InboundAuthKey>default</InboundAuthKey>
                <InboundAuthType></InboundAuthType>
                <Properties></Properties>
            </InboundAuthenticationRequestConfig>
        </InboundAuthenticationRequestConfigs>
    </InboundAuthenticationConfig>
    <LocalAndOutBoundAuthenticationConfig>
        <AuthenticationSteps>
            <AuthenticationStep>
                <StepOrder>1</StepOrder>
                <FederatedIdentityProviders>
                    <IdentityProvider>
                        <IdentityProviderName>kbank</IdentityProviderName>
                        <IsEnabled>true</IsEnabled>
                        <FederatedAuthenticatorConfigs>
                            <FederatedAuthenticatorConfig> 
                                <Name>MyAuthenticator</Name>
                                <IsEnabled>true</IsEnabled>
                            </FederatedAuthenticatorConfig>
                        </FederatedAuthenticatorConfigs>
                        <DefaultAuthenticatorConfig>MyAuthenticator</DefaultAuthenticatorConfig>
                        <JustInTimeProvisioningConfig>
                            <UserStoreClaimUri></UserStoreClaimUri>
                            <ProvisioningUserStore>PRIMARY</ProvisioningUserStore>
                            <IsProvisioningEnabled>true</IsProvisioningEnabled>
                        </JustInTimeProvisioningConfig>
                    </IdentityProvider>
                </FederatedIdentityProviders>
                <SubjectStep>true</SubjectStep>
                <AttributeStep>true</AttributeStep>
            </AuthenticationStep>
        </AuthenticationSteps>  
    </LocalAndOutBoundAuthenticationConfig>
    <RequestPathAuthenticatorConfigs></RequestPathAuthenticatorConfigs>
    <InboundProvisioningConfig></InboundProvisioningConfig>
    <OutboundProvisioningConfig></OutboundProvisioningConfig>
    <ClaimConfig>
        <AlwaysSendMappedLocalSubjectId>true</AlwaysSendMappedLocalSubjectId>
    </ClaimConfig>
    <PermissionAndRoleConfig></PermissionAndRoleConfig>
</ServiceProvider>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the default authenticator or rather the default sequence using the **application-authentication.xml** found in IS_HOME/repository/conf/identity. You can change this using the `<Sequences>` section.

Here as shown below the default sequence is set as a single step authentication sequence using the BasicAuthenticator

```
<Sequences>
        <!-- Default Sequence. This is mandatory -->
        <Sequence appId="default">
            <Step order="1">
                <Authenticator name="BasicAuthenticator"/>
            </Step>
        </Sequence>
</Sequences>
```

You can modify it to use any authenticator as the default. You need to specify the name of the authenticator.

Comment: Thanks farasath. I have tried your suggestion by replacing "BasicAuthenticator" with the Identity Provider name that I specified in API Manager carbon but got following exception at runtime.

`java.lang.NullPointerException
 org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.config.builder.FileBasedConfigurationBuilder.processStepElement(FileBasedConfigurationBuilder.java:645)`

Should API Manager pick up the configuration of the IDP from what I configure or do I need to specify the IDP properties anywhere else as well?