# Setting the default IdP for the API store applications in wso2

Tags: saml-2.0, wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm using a clustered environment with the Identity Server as the key manager. I've been trying to use implicit and authorization grants to test our applications and JWT claims. When I create an application it sets itself as a service provider with the Local & Outbound Authentication as default instead of our federated that is using SAML for Shibboleth. I followed this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35343448/set-wso2-identity-provider-as-default-idp-for-new-applications) and I tired multiple variations of it. I tried to configure two files in [IS_HOME] /repo/conf/identity/service-provider. The default.xml and sp_dashboard.xml. When I configure the sp_dashboard is seems like nothing happens. But when I configure the default.xml and try to get my access token through an implicit grant I get this error.

Additionally without any configuration everything works fine, but requires the user to login again with the implicit grants and authorization grants. Then when you login with implicit grants it me to the carbon with the access token in the URL, but authorization takes me to carbon without any code to use.

### LOG ERROR

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-01-09 14:48:36,323] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator} -  Exception in Authentication Framework java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.step.impl.DefaultStepHandler.handle(DefaultStepHandler.java:208) at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.sequence.impl.DefaultStepBasedSequenceHandler.handle(DefaultStepBasedSequenceHandler.java:173)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultAuthenticationRequestHandler.handle(DefaultAuthenticationRequestHandler.java:121)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.ipl.DefaultRequestCoordinator.handle(DefaultRequestCoordinator.java:137)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.CommonAuthenticationHandler.doPost(CommonAuthenticationHandler.java:46)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.CommonAuthenticationHandler.doGet(CommonAuthenticationHandler.java:37)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.endpoint.authz.OAuth2AuthzEndpoint.sendRequestToFramework(OAuth2AuthzEndpoint.java:1062)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.endpoint.authz.OAuth2AuthzEndpoint.authorize(OAuth2AuthzEndpoint.java:203)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:188) at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:104)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:204)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:101)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:249)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:248)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:222)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:153)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:171)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:289)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doGet(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:214)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:265
```

### Page Error

[image]

Here are my current configs

### SP_DASHBOARD

```
<ServiceProvider>
    <ApplicationID>2</ApplicationID>
    <ApplicationName>wso2_sp_dashboard</ApplicationName>
    <Description>Default Service Provider</Description>
    <InboundAuthenticationConfig>
            <InboundAuthenticationRequestConfigs>
                    <InboundAuthenticationRequestConfig>
                            <InboundAuthKey>wso2.my.dashboard</InboundAuthKey>
                            <InboundAuthType>samlsso</InboundAuthType>
                            <Properties></Properties>
                    </InboundAuthenticationRequestConfig>
            </InboundAuthenticationRequestConfigs>
    </InboundAuthenticationConfig>
    <LocalAndOutBoundAuthenticationConfig>
            <AuthenticationSteps>
                    <AuthenticationStep>
                            <StepOrder>1</StepOrder>
                            <FederatedIdentityProviders>
                            <IdentityProvider>
                                   <Name>IdPSSO</Name>
                                 <FederatedAuthenticatorConfigs>
                                         <FederatedAuthenticatorConfig>
                                                 <Name>SAMLSSOAuthenticator</Name>
                                         </FederatedAuthenticatorConfig>
                                 </FederatedAuthenticatorConfigs>
                             </IdentityProvider>
                            </FederatedIdentityProviders>
                            <SubjectStep>true</SubjectStep>
                            <AttributeStep>true</AttributeStep>
                    </AuthenticationStep>
            </AuthenticationSteps>
            <UseUserstoreDomainInUsername>true</UseUserstoreDomainInUsername>
            <UseTenantDomainInUsername>false</UseTenantDomainInUsername>
    </LocalAndOutBoundAuthenticationConfig>
   <RequestPathAuthenticatorConfigs></RequestPathAuthenticatorConfigs>
   <InboundProvisioningConfig></InboundProvisioningConfig>
    <OutboundProvisioningConfig></OutboundProvisioningConfig>
    <ClaimConfig>
      <AlwaysSendMappedLocalSubjectId>true</AlwaysSendMappedLocalSubjectId>
   </ClaimConfig>
    <PermissionAndRoleConfig></PermissionAndRoleConfig>
```

### Default

```
<ServiceProvider>
    <ApplicationID>1</ApplicationID>
    <ApplicationName>default</ApplicationName>
    <Description>Default Service Provider</Description>
    <InboundAuthenticationConfig>
            <InboundAuthenticationRequestConfigs>
                    <InboundAuthenticationRequestConfig>
                            <InboundAuthKey>default</InboundAuthKey>
                            <InboundAuthType></InboundAuthType>
                            <Properties></Properties>
                    </InboundAuthenticationRequestConfig>
            </InboundAuthenticationRequestConfigs>
    </InboundAuthenticationConfig>
    <LocalAndOutBoundAuthenticationConfig>
            <AuthenticationSteps>
                    <AuthenticationStep>
                            <StepOrder>1</StepOrder>
                            <FederatedIdentityProviders>
                             <IdentityProvider>
                                   <Name>IdPSSO</Name>
                                 <FederatedAuthenticatorConfigs>
                                         <FederatedAuthenticatorConfig>
                                                 <Name>SAMLSSOAuthenticator</Name>
                                         </FederatedAuthenticatorConfig>
                                 </FederatedAuthenticatorConfigs>
                             </IdentityProvider>
                            </FederatedIdentityProviders>
                            <SubjectStep>true</SubjectStep>
                            <AttributeStep>true</AttributeStep>
                    </AuthenticationStep>
            </AuthenticationSteps>
    </LocalAndOutBoundAuthenticationConfig>
    <RequestPathAuthenticatorConfigs></RequestPathAuthenticatorConfigs>
    <InboundProvisioningConfig></InboundProvisioningConfig>
    <OutboundProvisioningConfig></OutboundProvisioningConfig>
    <ClaimConfig>
      <AlwaysSendMappedLocalSubjectId>true</AlwaysSendMappedLocalSubjectId>
   </ClaimConfig>
    <PermissionAndRoleConfig></PermissionAndRoleConfig>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find out the config I had to do. It was in the IS default.xml. It looks like the IsEnabled was the important part missing in my config.

```
<FederatedIdentityProviders>
    <IdentityProvider>
      <IdentityProviderName>IdPSSO</IdentityProviderName>
          <IsEnabled>true</IsEnabled>
       <FederatedAuthenticatorConfigs>
         <FederatedAuthenticatorConfig>
            <Name>SAMLSSOAuthenticator</Name>
            <IsEnabled>true</IsEnabled>
          </FederatedAuthenticatorConfig>
       </FederatedAuthenticatorConfigs>
       <DefaultAuthenticatorConfig>SAMLSSOAuthenticator</DefaultAuthenticatorConfig>
     </IdentityProvider>
</FederatedIdentityProviders>
```